# How can I stop auto spacing in VS code in a react file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

This is the code I'm writing in my VS code in my JSX file, but it's showing an error as it is not recognising `< /h1>` as a closing tag.
I tried so many ways to stop this auto spacing, but I'm unable to do it.

Please help as soon as you can!!
Thank you!

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render( < h1 > Hello < /h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is something to do with the Language Mode you have got. Use the JavaScript (React) Language mode with Prettier to avoid it.

To change the Language Mode, press <kbd>F1</kbd> and type in Change Language Mode and you'll get something like this:

[image: change lang mode]

Use JavaScript (React) in it. And try saving again and it should work.

Comment: It's already been set to prettier. But still, the same thing is happening.

Comment: @HimanjliJain It should be `JavaScript (React)` and not `JavaScript`. Did you check that?

Answer (score 0):

In my `formatter.JSON` file, which pops up after clicking F1 and typing in the name of the file. I had to change:

```
"javascript": {
  "space_before_conditional": false,
}
```

`"space_before_conditional"` value to `false` under the `"javascript"` object and it is now working fine.

Comment: I think this doesn't solve it. Because I have got `true` in mine!

Comment: Yes you have to set it to false.

Comment: No, you don't. Leave it that way, coz you need something like `if (a < b)`, you see?